# Linear transformation of orthogonal complement

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality

Let $T\colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be linear. If $W$ is a $T$-invariant subspace, then $W^\perp$ (under the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$) is also $T$-invariant. Is this true? I don't think it is, but I'm not sure how to prove it, a push in the right direction would be appreciated. If not true, please avoid giving counter-examples as I would like to understand why this is not true in general.

Comment: What is the definition of a T-cyclic subspace?

Comment: Oops, I meant to write $T$-invariant, edited. A subspace $W$ of $V$ is $T$-invariant if $T(W) \subset W$.

Comment: Is $W$ also a vector subspace?

Comment: Yes, $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: The statement is true under the additional hypothesis that $T$ is self-adjoint. Without a hypothesis like that, there's no reason for $T$-invariance to have any relationship to the inner product.

Comment: I included the inner product for the definition of the orthogonal complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the matrix $A=(u_1,u_2)$ in columns, where $u_1=(1,0)$ and $u_2=(x,1)$ for some $x\neq 0$. $E=\{(a,0);a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is invariant for $A$ but your orthogonal complement is not.